# android switch layout on rotate

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation, android-videoview

I have an activity with a videoview and a button, I have two different layout, one for portrait mode and second for landscape.

So, I create layout-land for second layout, and all works fine.

The problem is when rotation occours. Videoview restart becouse Activity renew. 
Setting in manifest orientation|screensize video not restart, but I lose landscape layout.

How to do both tasks ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `configChanges` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, but also make use of `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` to put the activity back in to the state you want it to be in after the orientation has changed.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) for more details

Comment: on device rotation if I set configChanges="orientation" onCreate method not called , but I don't have layout-land . In onSaveInstance application goes only when screen goes off or press on home button.